# How to select same column's name from different table in Linq?

Tags: linq

I've 2 tables with same column's name, for example, both table A and table B has column's name "Test". I want to select column Test from both table A and B to entity class. How can I do this?

Comment: Do that table have any relations?

Comment: @zerkms: Table A has relation to table B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the two entities of TableA and TableB merged into a new object. You can use the `.Select()` extension method to create a new anonymous type, or into a class that you already have defined.

The requirement here is that you've got to find a common attribute between TableA and TableB. Here I assume you've got something like `ID` to match them together.

**Anonymous Type**

```
 var mergedTests =  from a in db.TableA
                    join b in db.TableB on a.CommonID equals b.CommonID
                    select new 
                           { TestFromA = a.Test, TestFromB = b.Test }
                    .ToList();
```

**Existing Class**

```
 List<MyCustomTests> mergedTests =  from a in db.TableA
                    join b in db.TableB on a.CommonID equals b.CommonID
                    select new MyCustomTests 
                       { TestName= a.Test, ShortName= b.Test }
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: This is not I want, I want to select column Test from both table A and B to same row but different column name. E.g. TestA and TestB are in same row.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var A = new Data[] {
            new Data { Test = 1, Relation = 1 },
            new Data { Test = 2, Relation = 2 },
            new Data { Test = 3, Relation = 3 },
            new Data { Test = 4, Relation = 4 },
            new Data { Test = 5, Relation = 5 },
        };

        var B = new Data[] {
            new Data { Test = 2, Relation = 2 },
            new Data { Test = 3, Relation = 3 },
            new Data { Test = 5, Relation = 5 },
        };

        var res = from a in A
                  join b in B on a.Relation equals b.Relation
                  select new { TestA = a.Test, TestB = b.Test };
    }
}

class Data
{
    public int Test;
    public int Relation;
}
```